# passing Multiple string values in SSRS using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I'm fairly new at stored procedures and using them with SSRS.

I want to create a simple SSRS report using a Stored Procedure with a parameter allowing multiple values (results from a separate Procedure)

I have 2 simple stored procedures as Follows.

```
Create Procedure WO
@STARTDATE datetime, @ENDDATE datetime, @DISTRICT varchar(25)
AS
SELECT A.WO, A.CUST, A.DISTRICT, A.COMPL_DATE
FROM WORK_ORDERS A
WHERE A.COMPL_DATE between (@STARTDATE) and (@ENDDATE) 
and A.DISTRICT_NAME in (@DISTRICT)

Create Procedure DISTRICT
AS
SELECT B.DISTRICT_NAME
FROM DISTRICTS B
```

In my SSRS report, I'm reporting the WO Procedure using the result(s) from the DISTRICT procedure using a "DISTRICT" parameter with the available values from the DISTRICT procedure (ALLOWING MULTIPLE VALUES).  Also I've used the DISTRICT Parameter in the Parameters of the WO procedure.

This works when selecting **one** District, but not when I select multiple districts.  Anyone out there willing to help?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the problem is handling the string parameter @district - presumably, SSRS is passing something that looks like "N,S,E,W", assuming 4 districts were selected - the stored proc would then come out as: ...A.District_Name in ('N,S,E,W')... which would only return a value if there were a district name 'N,S,E,W'. So, I think you need to split the incoming value and reassemble it as 'N','S','E','W'. Unfortunately, there's no SPLIT function in SQL Server, so you either have to write a UDF (there are several posts available) or make a CLR call.

Here's a clever (and untested) thought - try Replace(@District,',',''',''') (I think I got the quotes right...)